# checking for the existence of a word a mysql row(php)

Tags: php, mysql

i have a mysql table `users` like this:

```
id      username     following
15      one          ,13,14,16,17,
14      two          ,76,43,13,
13      three        null
```

now three has 0 following and 2 followers.
and i want a query to check for all users who have `,13,` in the following row

Something like this:

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE following has ",13,"');
```

but works.

I can select all the following of each user and do this:

```
if (strpos($result_from_query,',13,') !== false) {
    echo $fetch['username'];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using LIKE? `$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE following LIKE "%,13,%"');` The % before and after is a wildcard for any characters can be there, so will find `,13,` in any position in the string

Comment: @Stu post that as an answer

Comment: No probs, hope it helps... also take a look at @Jay Blanchard's answer as another option

Comment: I would recommend moving your follower data to another table - you'll get into a world of scaling trouble if you have to use `LIKE` on this. It won't use column indexes, so past a certain size may cause speed issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)?

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE following LIKE "%,13,%"');
```

The % characters before and after the `,13,` string act as a wildcard allowing any characters to be there, so will find ,13, in any position in the string.

Also, as an aside, @Jay Blanchard has suggested using the [IN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator ([in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29561653/checking-for-the-existence-of-a-word-a-mysql-rowphp/29561791#29561791))

Answer (score 1):

I would use `IN` for greater flexibility *if the value in the `following` column is an array*.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `following` IN(13)
```

Comment: Between `LIKE` and `IN`? Yes. `LIKE` is saying I want to match something nearly exactly. `IN` is essentially an `OR` statement, so you could match *one* `OR` *another*. For instance, I need to find folks who have follower A or B @thesofasker

Comment: Can you do this on a string field, Jay? I thought that would only work if the field is equal to any item in the `IN` - I think a wildcard is needed here.

Comment: Thanks Jay. [I've created this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91fb3), which accords with my experience - I don't think it can do the `%` wildcarding that would be necessary to fetch the inserted row. Have I misunderstood your post?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I wasn't clear. With `IN` you cannot use the wildcards but you can use strings. In this case the commas really are not necessary and it would be better to use `IN` straight up - testing against the array in that column.

Comment: Yes, so if you have these three followers in this order: `76,43,13` then you can do an `IN (",76,43,13,")`, but I guess you can't use `IN` if you want to return any users who follow 13 and any others?

Comment: Correct. IMHO if you're storing an array as a string in a column that would just be bad planning.

Comment: Definitely agreed there - I think that is what they are doing.

Comment: Yeah, I think they are storing an array too. I made a correction to my answer which makes it more accurate.

Comment: (Sorry, I should have been clearer: I think they are using a CSV string. But I see how yours works now - I wasn't aware there was an array type in MySQL - good to know).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the numbers always have starting and trailing commas you can use:

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE following LIKE "%,13,%"');
```

Please read up on [LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) statements for more info